# OWIN Startup error

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

i get the following error message, if i start my application using a self hosted web api (OWIN):

> {"The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.\r\n - 
>       For the app startup parameter value '....PlugIn.WebService.Startup, ....PlugIn.WebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>       PublicKeyToken=null', the assembly '....PlugIn.WebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' was not found.":""}

Owin is implemented in a dynamic loaded assmbly.

The error occurse in the following line:

```
webApiDisposable = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress);
```

Base url is: `http://localhost:42015/`

The startup looks like:

```
public class Startup
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Configurate the new http client
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="appBuilder">OWIN App builder</param>
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        string routeTempl = "api/" + EndpointManager.API_VERSION + 
                            "/{controller}/{action}/{id}";

        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: routeTempl,
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Attribute routing
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Set all filter, like for authentication and autoriuation
        config.Filters.Add(new IntegratedAuthorization());

        // Setup Json-return
        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings =
        new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        };

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

The curious thing is, that in another project it works just fine. I also tried the `Owin.Start-Attribute`.

Comment: The problem may be a missing reference, or a bad web.config or something like that.

Comment: I don't need any web.config (Because it is self hosted and a windows service). Nuget should have load all needed dependencies. Thas seems to be complete.

Comment: What is Plugin.WebService and why can't it find it?  That's what the error is directing you to.  That's why I think it has nothing to do with this code.

Comment: The PlugIn.Webservice is a simple Dll, which is loaded dynamically with `Assembly.Load...`. The the method that calls `webApiDisposable = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress);` is in the core of our system.

Comment: It is trying to load that DLL and failing.  You need to figure out why it can't load that DLL.  And why it thinks it needs that DLL.  I would remove dependencies on it for now, and see if it works, then add it back in piecemeal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it couldn't find the `Startup` class when launching the program. It was not an OWIN-only-related problem, but maybe it can be for the same reason.

For some reasons, the Assembly name of the web service was changed and unfortunately it was the same as another assembly referenced by the same project.

Of course, they conflicted.
The solution was to rename the Assembly.

I know it's quite late to help BendEg, but maybe this can be useful for someone else.